# Php count registered users

Tags: php, sql, database

I am learning php and creating a basic site with a "Control Panel". Right now I'm encountering an error with my code while attempting to get the amount of registered users.
My database:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.2.12deb2+deb8u2
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Jul 25, 2017 at 06:10 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.55-0+deb8u1
-- PHP Version: 5.6.30-0+deb8u1

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `login`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_uname` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `user_email` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `user_pwd` varchar(256) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `user_uname`, `user_email`, `user_pwd`) VALUES(1, 'Test1', 'johndoe@mail.com', 'HashedPassword');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
MODIFY `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

The index.php file is

```html
<?php
include dbh.inc.php;
?>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Sidebar-Test</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/flaticon.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
 <div class="logo"><a href='#'>Side<span>Source</span></a></div>
</div>
<div id="container">

  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul id="nav">
      <li><span class="flaticon-graphic"></span><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
      <li><span class="flaticon-download"></span><a href="#">Download</a></li>
      <li><span class="flaticon-settings-work-tool"></span><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

 <div class="content">
  <h1>Dashboard</h1>
  <div id="box1" class="box">
  <h3>Users</h3>
  <p id="Box1P">
<?php
$sql = "select COUNT(user_id) registered_users from users";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("Query error!");


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $var = $row['registered_users'];

    echo "There are currently " .$var. " users.";

}
?>
  </div>
 </div>
 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And dbh.inc.php:

```html
<?php

$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "login";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

if (!$conn) {
 die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

I've tried error-reporting but `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` returned nothing, but entering `select COUNT(user_id) registered_users from users` in phpmyadmin would return 
registered_users
1.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the error that you're encountering?

Comment: `include dbh.inc.php;` should be `include 'dbh.inc.php';` (it's a string)

Comment: I really hope that the login data you provided is completely altered and your not actually logging into your database as `root`.

Comment: what did php's error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php give you back about your `include dbh.inc.php;`, undefined constant? file not found?

Comment: ...or undefined index? I have my money on this one actually.

Comment: I cannot find the error, all errors aren't displayed, solutions to this?

Comment: And @GrumpyCrouton, yeah, the login's changed.

Comment: The question is closed so I can't put in an answer, but here's your problem: After the query, you're setting $var to $row['__count__']. However, you're actually aliasing the count to `registered_users` in the query. You should instead have: `$var = $row['registered_users'];`

Comment: @RobbieToyota, I fixed the error, to no avail. I'll update the code here.

Comment: Can you output `mysqli_num_rows($result)` to see if any data was returned? If there was data returned, can you output `print_r($row)` in your while loop, as well?

Comment: No output returns, in neither.

Comment: Ok, god I'm an idiot, thanks to what @Fred-ii- said I realised my dbh file wasn't in the same directory.... it was in the /includes/ folder thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql = "select COUNT(user_id) registered_users from users";
$var = $row['count'];
```

You select the count *as* `registered_users` but you're trying to read a field `count` which does not exist. Use `$row['registered_users']` instead.

Comment: I did, thanks for the catch on that error, the database error still stands though.

Answer (score 0):

Change your sql with this:

```
$sql = "select COUNT(user_id) from users";
```

And try to assign the value as:

```
$var = $row['COUNT(user_id)'];
```

Comment: No apperant effects, thanks for your time though!